# OpenGL ES - Where is EAGLView.h? xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, xcode4.2

Hello I'm very new to OpenGlES and i have started to try to learn it with online tutorials... but in each tutorial they ask me to create a OpenGL ES Xcode project, and then edit EAGLView.h. But I can't find it. Is it just me or has Xcode 4 changed its location etc. Also, when I run the application it gives me two cubes... 1 red and 1 blue... spinning around. In some tutorials, there is simply a multicoloured box, not in 3 dimensions. Is it possible to go back to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of EAGLView.h and m, they have moved all of the code into files named viewController.h and m.

If you have truly generated an "OpenGL Game" project as they are calling it in the newer versions of XCode!

In terms of the OpenGL code implemented to show the red and blue boxes etc... They have changed there sample code, you can from the m file put whatever you want there!!!

Comment: one of the tutorials is asking me to do this:

Comment: Open EAGLView.m in the editor and look for the following line:
#define USE_DEPTH_BUFFER 0

Comment: I think most of the examples that I have seen online, are written more for using OpenGL ES 1.0.  The Apple example as put together when you create a new project using XCode 4.0 and beyond I believe to be an OpenGL ES 2.0 example.  The line " #define USE_DEPTH_BUFFER 0" is not implemented with Apple' newest example!

Answer (score 1):

The sample application has changed significantly since the tutorials you are reading was written.

EAGLView, in its many incarnations, provided a `UIView` subclass that connected OpenGL to UIKit. As of iOS 5 there's no need for a custom class because of the introduction of GLKit. The modern OpenGL sample simply uses a `GLKView`, which is a built-in `UIView` subclass connecting OpenGL to UIKit.

What the sample actually shows has also changed to highlight the vector manipulation parts of GLKit that provide everything GL ES 1.1 supplied but which was cut from ES 2.0, and more.

If you want to work up from a tutorial, you're probably going to have to find a newer one. Searching for GLKit tutorials directly is probably the best idea — [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1) (amongst many others) looked like it covers mostly the modern stuff, for the sake of saying *something* rather than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample code from here and work from that:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLES2Sample/Introduction/Intro.html